# Laravel 5.5 on Heroku - php artisan down doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have recently deployed my Laravel 5.5 app on heroku. Everything works fine, except for the maintenance mode. The command `php artisan down` doesn't seem to work on heroku which works fine on my local machine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `down` command writes a file into the `<storagepath>/framework` folder named `down`. Make sure that's writeable.

Comment: I could see the down file present on the server. But the application won't turn down

Comment: What happens if you delete the one that's there and redo the down command?

Comment: It gets deleted automatically when I run `php artisan up` command. When  run the down command again it gets created.

Comment: If the file is there and it's just not going into maintenance mode, it sounds like maybe it's not readable then? If you `down` and then chmod 777 the `down` file does it work then?

Comment: File permissions are `-rw-------`

Comment: I couldn't find a solution to this problem. However, there seems to be some conflict when the app is hosted on Heroku. To solve my purpose I have customised the Heroku maintenance page using their API.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your storage folder have sufficient permission so try following steps:

1. Download Heroku CLI from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli
2. Login to heroku with heroku login command
3. Try `heroku run php artisan down --app appname`

You can directly make maintenance on mode on heroku that is visiting https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/appname/settings

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem is to use `heroku maintenance:on` and `heroku maintenance:off` which use Heroku's maintenance mode instead.